# IAP Billing Subscription not working well

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have an issue cancelling my iap subscription.

Platform: Android
IAP Version: 1.22.0
Unity: 5.5.6f1

I have bought a renewable subscription. 
Then, I cancelled it from Play Store.
So, I expected the susbcription to expire. In the Play Store it is not shown anymore.

But, when I logged into my app again I ask for the subscription status.
Google returns me that the subscription is actived, is subscribed, was not canceled or expired.
If I try to buy a new subscription Play store brings me an error that I already have a susbcription

Is it a bug?
Only happens in test mode or could happens in production?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked free trial? Your subscription could have free trial so Google Play still tells you that it is active.

If not, then there is a lag between cancellation and Google Play revoke the item from client cached results.